# MongoDB - Shell Scripting - $in usage in $ref

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

How can I use the `$in` correctly in `$ref`?

```
 cursor = db.MyCollection.find({
    "player": {
    "$ref": "Contact",
    "$id": {
        $in: [ObjectId("556d901118bfd4901e2a3833"), ObjectId("556d901118bfd4901e2a3833")]
    }    ^ it executes successfully, but does not find anything
    }
})
```

Is it even possible to use `$in` inside a `$ref` ?

Comment: Don't use DBRef. It's bad news. Construct your references manually. Or better yet, "embed" where you can.

Comment: Can't you just do `db.MyCollection.find({'player.$id': {$in: [ObjectId(...),ObjectId(...),ObjectId(...)]}})`?